# Memory optimization and RAM extend with HDF5 or Pickle

Tags: python, optimization, memory-management, pandas, pickle

I have a load a very large datafile which is bigger than my RAM. I try to do that both with Pickle and HDF5 but the data are loaded in memory.
Is there a way to access data without load them on memory but accessing to them directly on the Disk ?

```
from memory_profiler import profile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cPickle
import gc
import time

basepath = '/Users/toto/Desktop/'

@profile
def test_write():
    dim = 10000000
    df = pd.DataFrame({'test':range(dim)}, index=range(dim))
    for i in range(30):
        df[str(i)]=df['test'] * np.random.normal(0,1)

    print 'df created'
    cPickle.dump(df, open(basepath + 'df_pickle', 'wb'))
    gc.collect()
    store = pd.HDFStore(basepath + 'df_HDFpd')
    store['df'] = df
    store.close()
    gc.collect()
    del df
    gc.collect()

@profile
def test_read(method):
    print method
    if method == 'pickle':
        df = cPickle.load(open(basepath + 'df_pickle', 'rb'))
    if method == 'HDF':
        store = pd.HDFStore(basepath + 'df_HDFpd')
        df = store['df']
    print df.head(5)

    try:
        store.close()
    except:
        pass


#test_write()

timer = time.time()
test_read('HDF')
print 'Execution time: 'time.time()-timer
```

Result for test_write():

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    12     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    13                             def test_write():
    14     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       dim = 10000000
    15    969.4 MiB    926.8 MiB       df = pd.DataFrame({'test':range(dim)}, index=range(dim))
    16   3029.7 MiB   2060.3 MiB       for i in range(30):
    17   3029.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           df[str(i)]=df['test'] * np.random.normal(0,1)
    18                             
    19   3029.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       print 'df created'
    20   3029.7 MiB      0.1 MiB       cPickle.dump(df, open(basepath + 'df_pickle', 'wb'))
    21   2616.7 MiB   -413.0 MiB       gc.collect()
    22   2619.7 MiB      3.0 MiB       store = pd.HDFStore(basepath + 'df_HDFpd')
    23   2695.3 MiB     75.5 MiB       store['df'] = df
    24   2695.4 MiB      0.1 MiB       store.close()
    25   2696.1 MiB      0.7 MiB       gc.collect()
    26   1319.8 MiB  -1376.3 MiB       del df
    27   1319.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Result for test_load('HDF'):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    29     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   
    30                             @profile
    31     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   def test_read(method):
    32     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       print method
    33                                 if method == 'pickle':
    34     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           df = cPickle.load(open(basepath + 'df_pickle', 'rb'))
    35     46.7 MiB      4.2 MiB       if method == 'HDF':
    36   2488.7 MiB   2442.0 MiB           store = pd.HDFStore(basepath + 'df_HDFpd')
    37   2489.2 MiB      0.5 MiB           df = store['df']
    38                                 print df.head(5)
    39   2489.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   
    40   2489.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       try:
    41                                     store.close()
    42                                 except:
    43                                     pass
```

Result for test_load('cPickle'):

to come in few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `h5py`, when you index into an `H5File` it gives you something which is not a NumPy array, but is convertible to one.  So you should slice that, or operate on it directly in some way, which can avoid reading the entire thing into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used HDFs yet, but it looks like you can read an HDF in incrementally with [pandas.read_hdf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html#pandas.read_hdf), either using the start/stop arguments or by getting it to return an iterator.